# parsing json на несколько структур

Tags: json, golang, struct

Я пытаюсь с запроса, который поступает на сервер, разобрать json   и полученные данные разбить на несколько структур для дальнейшего  сохранения в базу

Есть вот такой json

```
 {  "name":"test", "category" : "test", "questions" : [{"question":"blabla"}] }
```

и  есть такие структуры

---

```
type Vote struct {
gorm.Model
Name     string 
Category string }
```

---

```
type VoteQuestion struct {
gorm.Model
NumberQuestion int  
ListQuestions  string
Vote           Vote

VoteID         int}
```

Каким образом сделать разборку? Создать промежуточною структуру для сохранения данных?

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. Покажите код. Что вы делаете, и что не получается.

Answer (score 1):

## Замечания по вопросу

Обе твои структуры не валидные для парсинга.
**Первая структура** имеет публичные поля ([начинаются с большой буквы](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers)), но не совпадают с полями из json. **name != Name**. Это не будет *распарсено*. 
Нужно сопоставить поля из структуры с полями из json через [теги](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal).

```
type Vote struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    Category string `json:"category"`
}
```

**Для второй структуры**.Ты используешь gorm - значит база реалиционная. Все поля должны быть примитивами, но я не понимаю почему ты хранишь массив объектов *"questions"* как строку. Подразумеваю, что поле *"questions"* предпологается хранить как строку. Тогда:

```
type VoteQuestion struct {
    gorm.Model
    NumberQuestion int
    ListQuestions  string `json:"questions,string"`
    Vote           Vote
    VoteID         int
}
```

Тэг *`json:"questions,string"`* где *string* значит оставить поле строкой. То есть не парсить это поле, а вставить "сырое" json поле. [Описание.](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal)

## Ответ на вопрос

**I. Вручную**. Создать структуру которая будет парсить json полностью. И сортировать нужные данные в конечные структуры.

**II. Полуручную**. Парсить весь json в одну структуру которая использует тэги для gorm. С тегами можно игнорировать определенные поля структуры при вставке в таблицу. А вторую структуру заполнить в ручную.

```
type Vote struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    Category string `json:"category"`
    ListQuestions  string `json:"questions,string" sql:"-"`
}
```

Тэг *`sql:"-"`* игнорит поле при вставке в таблицу.

**III. Автоматически**. Создать две структуры. И распарсить в json в каждую структуру отдельно.

```
raw, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
vote := Vote{}
err = json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(raw)).Decode(&vote)
voteQuestion := VoteQuestion{}
err = json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(raw)).Decode(&voteQuestion)
```

Сначала читаем все байты из тела запроса. Потом создаем два json декодера.